# Question about scalar product of 2 four-vectors

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity

I'm looking for help to prove that $\mathbf{a\cdot b}=-ab\ cosh \ \theta$, where:

$a=\sqrt{\mathbf{-a\cdot a}}$,

$b=\sqrt{\mathbf{-b\cdot b}}$, and

$cosh \ \theta$ is $\gamma$, for a Lorentz boost that would move you from a frame where a is at rest to a frame where b is at rest.

I started by ignoring the y and z coordinates, and expanding **a**, **b**, and $\gamma$ in terms of time, length, and velocity.  That gave me:

$(\sqrt{(a^t)^2-(a^x)^2}) \ (\sqrt{(b^t)^2-(b^x)^2}) \ (\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-V^2}})$

That left me scratching my head about what V is and I got totally derailed.  I couldn't figure out if V is the velocity associated with a Lorentz Transformation that would transform **a** into **b**, or whether I was supposed to somehow get a velocity from $\frac{b^x}{b^t}-\frac{a^x}{a^t}$, and in any event, all of these approaches seemed to be leading off into thickets of horrendous algebra, instead of towards the answer I want:

$\mathbf{a\cdot b}=-a^tb^t+a^xb^x$

(Yes, I have reviewed the earlier discussion of this issue but I couldn't follow it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof of this identity is entirely analogous to how one would go about proving the Euclidean formula $\vec{a}.\vec{b} = |a||b| \text{cos}(\theta)$.

What one has to do is as follows:

1. Find a matrix $M(\theta)$ such that $\vec{b} = M(\theta)\vec{a}$.
2. Use the definition of the inner product $\vec{a}.\vec{b}$.
3. Relate the two equations above to solve for $\theta$.

Let me sketch how to do it for the Minkowski space spanned by $(t,x)$, namely $\mathbb{R}^{1,1}$. The inner product between two vectors $a,b \in \mathbb{R}^{1,1}$ is given by $a.b = -a^0 b^0 + a^1 b^1$.

Let $a$ and $b$ be members of $\mathbb{R}^{1,1}$ for which there exists a matrix $\Lambda(\alpha) \in SO(1,1)$ and a constant $c$ such that $$b = c\Lambda(\alpha) a.$$ The matrix $\Lambda(\alpha)$ takes the standard form

$$\begin{pmatrix}
\text{cosh}(\alpha) & -\text{sinh}(\alpha) \\
-\text{sinh}(\alpha) & \text{cosh}(\alpha)
\end{pmatrix}$$
and one can get that $$c = \frac{|b|}{|a|}$$ by taking the norm of both sides and noticing that $\Lambda(\gamma)$ preserves the norm.

Then doing the procedure above one can reduce it to the desired equation.

Comment: Thanks that's super helpful.  I assume you meant to express the matrix with negative sinh.  I guess the moral of the story was to think solely in terms of rapidity, and not to forget the renormalization step after you rotate from a to b.

Comment: Ah yes, that's the standard way of writing it. Glad it helped!